# Error when AgGridReact rowData changes when a column has a cellRenderer that returns a React component

Tags: javascript, redux, ag-grid, redux-saga

Given an `AgGridReact` component like the following:

```js
<AgGridReact rowData={myData}>
    <AgGridColumn field="status" cellRenderer={() => <span />} />
</AgGridReact>
```

When I pass a different value to the `myData` prop, I get the following error:

> ag-Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, eg instead of api.refreshView(), call setTimeout(function(){api.refreshView(),0}). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.

The problem does not occur if the `cellRenderer` is replaced with `() => 'foo'`.

I am not calling any grid API methods. From the stack trace, the offending API call is internal (invoked because `rowData` changed).

The `rowData` prop is from the Redux store. It's changing as a result of an action dispatched from a saga. This may or may not be relevant.

Comment: Could you please confirm are you using any cell stylings or using enums properties to render the rowData?

Comment: I reproduced the problem in a minimal example resembling the sample code in the question, with no styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cellRendererFramework` fixed the problem. Something like:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() { return <span />; }
}
<AgGridColumn field="status" cellRendererFramework={MyComponent} />
```

It's a bit inconvenient, but it works.

Comment: can you help me on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231178/angular-ag-grid-undo-selected-row-changes-on-button-click

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this and doesn't have the specific above error, I encountered this error when I had a bug in a tooltip renderer (I was trying to call filter on null), and the issue surfaced because HMR (Hot Module Reloading) was refreshing my component differently than from a cold start.

After pulling out some hair and Googling until every link was purple, I added some custom logging to ag-grid itself. In ag-grid-community.amd.js (you might need a different one), I added the following to `getLockOnRefresh()` so I could understand what was calling getLockOnRefresh, where this error gets thrown.

`console.log('hi there', throw new Error().stack)`

Then I added some debug statements in the web inspector, and eventually found the actual error in my tooltip renderer.

So consider this a warning beacon around ag-grid and HMR potentially swallowing errors and leading you down the wrong path for a while.

This probably doesn't matter, but in case it's relevant, I'm also using React, Redux, Immer, and my site is loaded in Electron.